# Let $G$ be a disconnected graph. Then $\overline{G}$ is connected. Prove that if $u,v \in V(G)$, then $d_{\overline{G}}(u,v)=1$ or $2$,$diam(G)\leq 2$

Tags: graph-theory

I'm having a hard time proving this one without bringing up special constraints. The way I see it, we can take this into cases. The first case supposes $u$ and $v$ are adjacent in $G$. The second case supposes the opposite.

**Case 1:** Suppose $uv$ is not an edge in $G$, then $uv$ is an edge in $\overline{G}$. Hence, $d_{\overline{G}}(u,v)=1$.

**Case 2:** Suppose $uv$ is an edge in $G$. Suppose there is a third vertex $x$ that is isolated from $u$ and $v$. Then $ux,vx$ will be an edge in $\overline{G}$ and so the path $P$ comprising $u$-$x$-$v$ will have length $2$.

I know Case 2 isn't right because it stipulates this weird vertex $x$ satisfying these weird constraints. Is there a better way to approach this problem? Is this not the right way to break this up into cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to think about the problem is the following:

If $G$ is disconnected, then it can be "split" into two graphs, $X$ and $Y$, so that there are no edges $uv$ where $u \in V(X)$ and $v \in V(Y)$ (and of course $V(X) \cap V(Y) = \emptyset$ and $V(X) \cup V(Y) = V(G)$). Then, $\overline{G}$ must contain **every** edge $uv$ where $u \in V(X)$ and $v \in V(Y)$!

We can now use very similar cases that you use. If $u \in V(X)$ and $v \in V(Y)$, then clearly $uv$ is an edge. Thus, assume $u,v$ are both in $V(X)$ (the case when they are both in $V(Y)$ is similar.) We can pick *any* vertex  $y \in V(Y)$, and note that both $uy$ and $yv$ are edges, so the path has length $2$.